# How to use ImageMultiply[] over a list of strings?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, image

I'm trying to do the following:

```
l = FileNames[];
s[x_] := ToString[l[[x]]]
t = Table[s[x], {x, 1, Length[l]}];
i[x_] := Import[t[[x]]]
m[x_] := ImageMultiply[i[x], i[x + 1]]
```

This is supposed to take two images of one folder and multiply them. But I want to take two images and multiply them, then I want to take the next two, multiply them and multiply to the last multiplied images and proceed like this for all the images in the folder.

I already have a table with all the file locations, the problem is that `ImageMultiply[]` doesn't take lists as inputs. I wasn't able to do something like:

```
ImageMultiply[t]
```

Which would solve the problem, but the input of this function is:

```
ImageMultiply[image1,image2,...]
```

And not:

```
ImageMultiply[{image1,image2, ...}]
```

Perhaps there is some way of *drop* all the elements out of the list into that function, I don't know about it. I've also looked some functions that look extremelly similar to what I'm trying to do, I guess that there's some way to use `NestList[]` or `Nest[]` to do it, but [I've tried a few experiments and it resulted in hazard...$^1$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gob6.jpg)

$1$ - I don't remember precisely which arguments (then I chose arbitrary ones) I used in that function, but it really froze my computer.

Comment: Take a look at `Fold[]`

Comment: @belisarius [I've done the following.](http://i.imgur.com/FYyMaOb.png) But I have no idea on why it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
   SetDirectory["whatever"];
   Fold[ImageMultiply[#1, #2]&, #[[1]], Rest@##] &@ (Import/@ FileNames["*.gif"])
```

Comment: I'll do it, thanks. But could you explain a little further what's happening in there? It could be some references, I've looked the Mathematica documentation on this and I didn't get it.

Comment: @PristineKavalostka Err ..not much to say.It's a basic recursive form `Fold[f,x,{a,b}] -> f[f[x,a],b]`